# Paypal SandBox IPN History

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I use paypal for my payments. For verification i use [IPN](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro).
Can i review my INP History in the Paypal Sandbox?

At the [documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/images/developer/IPNHistory530w.gif)
 i see Instant Payment Notification History in the History tab.
(https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNOperations)

After [googling](http://wiki.opensource-excellence.com/images/thumb/7/74/PaypalIPNHistory1.png/900px-PaypalIPNHistory1.png) i see "IPN History" chapter in the History tab
(http://goo.gl/myZKF)

At the real [sandbox](http://ompldr.org/vZDVxOQ/Real.png) i don't see any IPN history.

Thank you.

Answer (score 36):

they hide it well:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history

Comment: and if direct link didn't work: Login -> History -> IPN History

Answer (score 3):

IPN History only available for business account not for personal account. You need to log in with your business account instead of personal account.

Answer (score 2):

Enable IPN within the PayPal account in order to start seeing 'IPN History'.
You can enable IPN within the account via the 'Profile' section.

Note: 'Enable' in this sense means that you enable IPN on the Profile level. You could still override (and use) IPN by passing notify_URL / NOTIFYURL in your transaction details.

Answer (score 2):

Alexandra i am also faced your situation, 
after sign in your paypal sandbox account click
**More > Site map**  here you can find **Instant Payment Notifications** in below listed items

Answer (score 0):

This is a tough one, as the Paypal Documentation provides a .gif but not a link.  Plus their documentation is horrendously out of date.

I couldn't find the Instant Payment Notification dashboard, but I did find this link:

https://www.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_merchant-hub

It should at least help you track down the customer ID.

Answer (score 0):

As per Srg's answer above [Paypal SandBox IPN History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877637/paypal-sandbox-ipn-history/#11450430)

Make sure you are logged in to **sandbox.paypal.com** account. Not in www.paypal.com account.

**For SANDBOX PayPal =>**

Login to your `sandbox.paypal.com` account with sandbox **BUSINESS** details.

You can get that Business account's Login Email ID and Password from *Profile tab* under View/Edit Account link provided inline with business account. After login follow this https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history link where you can see your IPN messages.