# No Paypal Sandbox IPN History. Notifications Not Working Despite Setup

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to do the simplest of "Hello World" IPN notifications in the PayPal sandbox, and it's not working despite my best efforts.

I tried checking the IPN history as described here:
[Paypal SandBox IPN History](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9877637/paypal-sandbox-ipn-history) ...but nothing is shown.

I checked my sandbox IPN configuration:
https://sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify-edit ...and it does show my IPN URL (set to "https://-random id-.ngrok.io/ipn"), but then when I make a transaction in the sandbox I receive no notification.

To summarize:

1. Sandbox IPN URL appears to be configured to my ngrok URL.
2. I try to perform a random transaction in Sandbox (using my personal PayPal account and a PayPal email link).
3. No notification comes through and nothing shows up on IPN history.

What am I missing?

Comment: What type of email link and "personal PayPal account" did you use to create the transaction? What is the transaction ID?

Comment: @PrestonPHX - I used a "Pay Now" button from here: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/buttons/ The account I used for the transaction is one that I'd normally use to pay for PayPal transactions in the real world (because it wouldn't let me complete a transaction with my sandbox merchant account, nor add fake credit cards).

Comment: Well we can't help further without knowing the sandbox email link or transaction ID

Comment: @PrestonPHX - Email link that I'm trying is: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/plans/subscribe?plan_id=P-0MK88614HR195721TL6MFGQA&custom=12345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the sandbox Business account receiving the payment has a confirmed email in the sandbox environment.

1. Log into it at https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email
2. Send the confirmation from there, if necessary
3. Read and proceed with the confirmation, via https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F

Comment: In step 1, my receiver email is listed as "Primary" and there's no link to send a confirmation. In step 3, that email doesn't appear under "test account emails" and when I click on "Show All Notifications" I see a message saying "You do not have any notifications." Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Comment: Your email should be confirmed now, test another payment

Comment: Thanks! How did you do that? Do you work for PayPal or something?